# Checked VisualState is not triggered after RadioButton is re-enabled

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, radio-button, visualstates

I'm working with a custom `RadioButton` control that is allows the user to give a rating between 1 and 5 depending on the selected `RadioButton`.

However, there are times in my application that the 5 `RadioButtons` are disabled, and then re-enabled.  When this happens the `VisualState` for the **Checked** `RadioButton` doesn't activate.  Instead, all 5 `RadioButtons` appear as the **Normal** state.

### Why is this happening?  How can I resolve this?

Here is the example of the `RadioButtons` that I'm using.

[image: RadioButton VisualStates]

If I start by selecting the first group of 5 `RadioButtons`, and make a selection, then everything may appear as the above image does.

But, if I select the second group of 5 `RadioButtons`, my control is designed so that the first group will disable.  This works fine, and the second group enables properly.  After that, if I select the first group again, every `Radiobutton` will appear with the **Normal VisualState**.  This is a problem, because my program knows that behind the scenes that **#1** is still **Checked**.  The **Checked VisualState** is NOT triggered, so it looks something like this:

[image: RadioButton VisualStates (error)]

The goal here is that the **Checked** `VisualState` will be resumed as it appears in the first image.

Here is the corresponding XAML code for the `VisualStates`:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
        <VisualState Name="Normal"/>
        <VisualState Name="Disabled">
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FillBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="#FFEEEEEE" Duration="0"/>
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="StrokeBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="#FF777777" Duration="0"/>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MoodEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeThickness" To="1" Duration="0"/>
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Presenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).Color" To="#FF777777" Duration="0"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
        <VisualState Name="Checked">
            <Storyboard>
                <ParallelTimeline>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FillBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="#FFC5F5FF" Duration="0:0:0.05"/>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="StrokeBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="#FF12394F" Duration="0:0:0.05"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MoodEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeThickness" To="2" Duration="0:0:0.05"/>
                </ParallelTimeline>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState Name="Unchecked"/>
        <VisualState Name="Indeterminate"/>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

This XAML code seems to be in accordance to how to use `VisualStates`, but I suppose there must be something wrong with it.

I've referenced these pages:

- [Customizing the Appearance of an Existing Control by Creating a ControlTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230084(v=vs.110).aspx#specifying_the_behavior_of_a_control_when_it_transitions_between_states)
- [RadioButton Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751600(v=vs.110).aspx)

As some additional notes, I've noticed that the **Checked** `VisualState` can be triggered if I click one of the **Unchecked** `RadioButtons`.  At this point, everything is works properly --until the group of `RadioButtons` is disabled & re-enabled.

Also, I've experience even stranger behavior for the **Checked** `VisualState` when I didn't include the empty **Unchecked** `VisualState` in the above XAML code.

Any insight about why the `VisualStates` are behaving strangely would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks much!

**EDIT:**

I'm not sure if it matters, but the group of `RadioButtons` are disabled because they are in `StackPanels` whose `IsEnabled` property is bound to the outside `RadioButton`'s `IsChecked` property:

```
<StackPanel IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type RadioButton}}, Path=IsChecked}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the problem is that I am using the same target properties within two different `VisualStateGroups`, [yet I'm not sure why this causes the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25812630/975724).

In order to have the desired affect, which is to display the **Checked** behavior after re-enabling, I created another `Ellipse` which is overlaid of the the original `Ellipse`.

The original `Ellipse` is fully opaque and it's **Fill/Stroke** properties are modified by the **CheckStates** group ONLY.

The new `Ellipse` is initially fully transparent (`Opacity="0"`), but the **Disabled** state causes the opacity to change to fully opaque.

This new `Ellipse` fades into into view and covers up the original `Ellipse`, which is showing the appearance of the **Checked/Unchecked** states.  This causes the overall result of the `RadioButton` to appear **Disabled**.

This fixed the problem describe in the OP, but it introduces a new issue:  the transition from the **Disabled** state to the **Checked** state is immediate.  This can be resolve by including this `VisualTransition` in the **CommonStates** group:

```
<VisualTransition From="Disabled" To="Checked" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.25"/>
```

Here is the final XAML used to solve the problem:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
        <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualTransition From="Disabled" To="Checked" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.25"/>
        </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
        <VisualState Name="Normal"/>
        <VisualState Name="Disabled">
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="EllipseOverlay" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.15"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
        <VisualState Name="Checked">
            <Storyboard>
                <ParallelTimeline>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FillBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="#FFC5F5FF" Duration="0:0:0.05"/>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="StrokeBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="#FF12394F" Duration="0:0:0.05"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MoodEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeThickness" To="2" Duration="0:0:0.05"/>
                </ParallelTimeline>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState Name="Unchecked"/>
        <VisualState Name="Indeterminate"/>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

In my control, I have this `Ellipse` appear after my original `Ellipse`, causing the new one to appear on top when the opacity increases.  Below is the new `Ellipse`:

```
<Ellipse x:Name="EllipseOverlay" StrokeThickness="1" Opacity="0" Fill="#FFEEEEEE" Stroke="#FF777777"/>
```

Note that this `Ellipse` contains the **Fill/Stroke** properties that were using the the OP's **Disabled** `VisualState`.